# Smooth closed simply-connected $4$-manifold with $w_1 = w_2 = 0$ without a point admits symplectic structure?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, sg.symplectic-geometry, characteristic-classes

See my previous question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/232215/tangent-bundle-of-smooth-closed-simply-connected-4-manifold-w-1-w-2-0-ca).

> Let $M$ be a smooth closed simply-connected $4$-manifold with $w_1 = w_2 = 0$. Can $TM$ be trivialized in the complement of a point?

This was answered in the affirmative.

My question now is, is it possible to conclude in some way from Smale's immersion theorem that $M - p$ admits a symplectic structure, where $p$ is a point? I see how to do it with Gromov's $h$-principal, but not with Smale's immersion theorem.

Comment: This is actually trivial (and you do not need simple connectivity): Take an immersion $M\to R^4$ and pull-back the symplectic structure from $R^4$ to $M$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By an application of Gromov's $h$-principle, an open manifold $W$ admits a symplectic structure precisely if $TW$ admits an almost complex structure. In the case you are considering it does, as $TW$ is trivial.

Comment: Thanks, but is there an easier way to see this that does not invoke something as powerful as Gromov's $h$-principle?

Comment: @Antonio: The h-principle for open $\text{Diff}(V)$-invariant relations is not so terrifying. There's a short proof in Eliashberg and Mishachev's book.